# HTML5 Video gallery playlist with multiple videos

Tags: html, video, gallery

I have a client that wants a video gallery that has a list of thumbnails on the left and a player area on the right. So far so good. I have some html5, jQuery and CSS that is playing a  single video in the right pane when a thumbnail is clicked.

My problem is, my client wants what is in essence two playlist.  For instance, a gallery of individuals that had a procedure would have a patient's photo as a thumbnail on the left, when the thumbnail is clicked, a video will start playing on the right about that patients experience. Then under that video there would be other links such as 1 week after surgery, 2 weeks after surgery etc.. Sort of a diary on an individual.

To see what I'm asking for, you can see a working one I have put together at http://www.smartlaserlift.com/video-diaries.html. This is a total hackjob using some ajax and really is not working cross platform the way I'd like.

Here is some markup I am currently working on just to display the thumbnails and play the video on the left. I am looking for suggestions on handling the second playlist or perhaps an idea on scrapping this and maybe a better way of doing it.

The HTML

```
<div class="video_gallery_container">
<div id="thumbs">
<a class="videoLink" videowidth="680" videoheight="383" videofile="Peggy_Web1" videothumb="peggy-vid-thumb" videocaption="Meet Peggy" videodescription="Meet Peggy as she begins her SmartLaser Lift Journey." ></a>
```

```
</div>
    <div id="vidContainer">
        <div id="videoPlayer">

        </div>
    </div>
```

The JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.videoLink').each(function() {
    var thumbnailFilePath = 'video/' + $(this).attr('videothumb') + '.jpg';
    var videoCaption = $(this).attr('videocaption');
        $(this).css('background-image','url('+thumbnailFilePath+')');
          $(this).html('<div class="caption">' + videoCaption + '</div><img class="play" src="images/play_icon.png" />');
});
$('.videoLink').click(function(){
    var videoFile = $(this).attr('videofile');
    var videoPoster = $(this).attr('videofile');
    var videoCaption = $(this).attr('videocaption');
    var videoWidth = Number($(this).attr('videowidth'));
    var videoHeight = Number($(this).attr('videoheight'));
    var videoDescription = $(this).attr('videoDescription');

        var videoCode = '<video width="'+videoWidth+'" height="'+videoHeight+'" controls autoplay autobuffer><source src="video/'+videoFile+'.ogv" type="video/ogg" /><source src="video/'+videoFile+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" /><object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="'+videoWidth+'" height="'+(videoHeight+40)+'" id="video_player" align="middle"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="movie" value="video_player.swf?videoFile=video/'+videoFile+'.mp4&amp;skinFile=video_skin.swf&amp;videoFileWidth='+videoWidth+'&amp;videoFileHeight='+videoHeight+'"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="scale" value="noscale"><param name="salign" value="lt"><embed src="video_player.swf?videoFile=video/'+videoFile+'.mp4&amp;skinFile=video_skin.swf&amp;videoFileWidth='+videoWidth+'&amp;videoFileHeight='+videoHeight+'" quality="high" width="'+videoWidth+'" height="'+(videoHeight+40)+'" name="video_player" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" scale="noscale" salign="lt" wmode="transparent" allowfullscreen="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed></object></video>';
        var playerBlock = '<div id="playerBlock"><div id="playerHeader">' + videoCaption + '</div>' + '<div id="player">' + videoCode + '</div><div id="videoDescription">' + videoDescription +'</div></div>';
        $('#videoPlayer').html(playerBlock);
        $('#videoPlayer').css('display', 'block');

        });

});//end document.ready function
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you got your links to work, but i need a code that will allow me to simply have 5 thumbnails on the left with a diffrent video playing when each thumbnail in click, similar to what you used, I'm not a coding expert and can not figure this out on my own.